# Fail to connect to MySQL server using C# but no issues using Workbench

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I'm busy pulling out my hair. It feels like the solution should be obvious or/and many others had the same issue. But I cant find a solution (maybe the lack of asking the right question).

PROBLEM:
I'm unable to connect with a MySQL server using C# code. I dont have issues connecting to another server using the same code (different credentials obviously).  And I dont have issues creating a connection or server instance of the 'problem' Server using Workbench. So it would suggest its not a port or rights issue on the server. Also, it cant be a code or MysqlConnector issue as there is no issues with the other server. error 1042

CODE:

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
string newCnnStr = "server=Win10Server;User Id=root;password=LamePassword;Persist Security Info=True;database=payrolldb;convert zero datetime=true";
        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(newCnnStr);
            conn.Open();
            txtTmpStatus.Text = "Connected";
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            txtTmpStatus.Text = "Check the Server String";
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 1042:
                    txtTmpStatus.Text = "Unable to connect to the Server";
                    break;
                case 0:
                    txtTmpStatus.Text = "Access denied";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return false;
```

I have also try adding the port 3306 to connection string - no change

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I replaced the IP address (which I should have tried hours ago) with the hostname and it work. So for some reason C# is not resolving the hostname. Suspect it could be related to the "-" in "Van-PC" as the other server does not have a "-" in its hostname. And yes, I know in my code sample the name is different.

Comment: Never mind, one of those days. The problem was that C# is case sensitive and Workbench is not. So when I used the host name all in caps, it worked in C#.